# App keep crashing, trying to have a Android Maps on my app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

I have an android app that I am making and trying to make use of Google maps. I have added a  maps fragment, and ran it to see what it looks like but it keeps crashing, what have I massed?

Here is my main class

```
package germanclub.blundenbusroute.co.za;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapFragment mapFragment =     (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.975449, 25.529952)).title("German Club Oktoberfest"));
    }
}
```

Here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="germanclub.blundenbusroute.co.za"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="Oktoberfest Shuttle Service"     android:icon="@drawable/germanclubcrest"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <activity android:name="Main"
                  android:label="Oktoberfest Shuttle Service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/lblwelcome" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/lblpickuppoint"
            android:text="@string/pickuppoint" android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblwelcome" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblpickuppoint" android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:id="@+id/radioGroup">
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NMMU"
                android:id="@+id/rdbNMMU" android:checked="true"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5 Ways Spar"
                android:id="@+id/rdb5Ways" android:checked="false"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sherwood Spar"
                android:id="@+id/rdbStadium" android:checked="false"/>
    </RadioGroup>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="350dp"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat? Did you register your map? I don't see the key on manifest.

Comment: please post you logical to be more clear with your question, also there're no permissions in your manifest required to show maps

Comment: Hi sorry, ive read over my code again, sorry made a very silly error of not getting the key for the google maps API

Answer (score 0):

You missed your Google Maps API key and target Google Play Services version in the manifest, didn't you?

See e.g. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config to learn how to setup maps.

Answer (score 0):

i cant see the key in the manifest ,

however if you are using Android Studio , you can create a new already configured google map project activity . but remember to register your map .